# Google Street View API crashes when a specific LatLng is used

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I get an IllegalArgumentException upon calling the code below

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetView ) {

    int radiusMeters = 50000; //50km
    streetView.setPosition(new LatLng(-33.911227,151.157825), radiusMeters); 

    //with this specific LatLng it should crash with 
    //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Out of texture space.
}
```

the application will only crash at this specific location (it does not crash at other locations or when the radius is >200km)

adding a try-catch at the 'setPosition()' method does not catch this error too.
**is there a way to catch this error and prevent the app from crashing?**

I am using 8.1.0 of the library

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'

I get the following crash log: -

```
10-13 22:34:51.954 30446-30571/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 766K, 46% free 7846K/14316K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
10-13 22:34:52.124 30446-30611/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 866K, 45% free 8013K/14316K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
10-13 22:34:52.265 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1009K, 44% free 8150K/14316K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
10-13 22:34:52.285 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 18.847MB for 8388624-byte allocation
10-13 22:34:52.295 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.305 30446-30446/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.315 30446-30446/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.335 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.415 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.445 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.505 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces D/TextLayoutCache: Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-13 22:34:52.535 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces W/dalvikvm: threadid=40: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4180bda0)
10-13 22:34:52.535 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Renderer
10-13 22:34:52.535 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces E/AndroidRuntime: Process: angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces, PID: 30446
10-13 22:34:52.535 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Out of texture space.
10-13 22:34:52.535 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.bg.a(Unknown Source)
10-13 22:34:52.535 30446-30583/angelandroidapps.twitch.TakeMePlaces E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.bg.run(Unknown Source) gmm6.streetview.bg.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade google play services to the latest 12.0.1 and use the latest setPosition method for streetViewPanorama which support OUTDOOR parameter.

`mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(location, 50, StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR);`

This OUTDOOR parameter solved the similar issue in my app (keep on getting exception when showing the street view of one specific POI).